# attach file in POST API request payload

Tags: node.js, api, testing, file-upload

I am using node js for testing apis. In 1 API i need to upload a file. I am not able to attach file in the payload. I am able to do it in postman but not do it with nodejs. I am using request-promise for managing requests. How can i go about it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slight modification in the @rustam's answer,

`return request({
        method: 'POST', 
        uri: 'http://localhost:8333',
        formData ={
            'file': fileStream,
        }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to specify the file in payload, then please look at this invented example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request-promise')

function sendFile() {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.txt');
    return request({
        method: 'POST', 
        uri: 'http://localhost:8333',
        body: readStream
    });
}

async function main() {
    const response = await sendFile();
    console.log({ response });
}

main();
```

In this example, I hard-coded the file name and url, but for you this may be function parameters.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, when i do this, i am getting "MultiValueDictKeyError", how can i resolve it?

Comment: This is not a mistake on your part, but on the server side, which is apparently written in python. Either you misunderstood how the server needs to send a file, or there is some kind of error in the server code. Do you have API documentation?